# Display settings do not show correct resolution options for secondary display

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I currently have installed Ubuntu 15.10 on an Acer Aspire E1-510 laptop with an Acer X223w as a secondary monitor. The graphics card is an Intel Bay Trail. The laptop resolution is fine but the secondary display is being limited to 1024x768 which is totally wrong. This is a 20 in HD widescreen display so it is capable of the 1366x768 that the built-in display is capable of. The systems settings show it of Unknown type. How, where, what do I have to configure to enable the full capability?

Here is the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 VGA`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display [8086:0f31] (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:0845]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

and the output of `xrandr -q`

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2390 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1366x768+1024+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 345mm x 194mm
   1366x768      59.99*+
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   680x384       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA1 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00* 
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: I have the same problem on LTE 16 with a Lenovo carbon X1 and a 30" Dell display.